# Android : Title of the Dialog is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, modal-dialog, android-actionbar, android-theme

In my application, I am calling a method of a 3rd party SDK which displays a full screen dialog.
But I do not see the title of this dialog.
For my app, I have set the theme to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar with
`<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` as I have to customize the action bar in every activity.

So, I think it is because of this theme, I am unable to see the title of the Dialog as I mentioned above. If I use the DarkActionBar for my app, I see the title of the Dialog.

My goal is to not use the DarkActionBar for my application but keep the same Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar as is while I still get to see the title of the dialog of 3rd party SDK. I cannot manually set the style to the dialog as this dialog is being created at the SDK level and my app has no control over it.

Is there any way around to make this happen?

Comment: Is using the aforementioned 3rd party SDK for displaying full-screen dialog required/mandatory? Since you mentioned your app has no control over it, getting rid of the SDK and implement a custom full-screen dialog is a better approach. You can experiment with changing themes, if you suspect that's the reason but that's just assumption-based & could potentially not be the case too.

Comment: @SaadAAkash Oh yeah it is mandatory. I am using a library to shown the imprint sand other documents from a server. and all i need to provide is the api key and name of the file. Rest the library takes care and displays the html files in a dialog